# Do you have specific techniques for learning/memorizing python functions?

Tags: python

I am currently learning python and have been struggling learning new functions. There always seems to be a perfect match for functions I need and I never think of them until I see them utilized elsewhere. Is this normal? Does it happen to veteran programmers as well?

for example this snippet in learnpythonthehardway:

```
PHRASE_FIRST = False
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english":
    PHRASE_FIRST = True
```

I would have never thought of doing that without going in circles first.

Do you have specific mnemonic techniques for memorizing stuff? Can anyone share their insights?

Comment: the technique is called 'practice' :)

Comment: A way from your question, the code you have written has a syntax error. The last line should be indented to right by one tab.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed.

Comment: Of, course, I understand practising everyday is the answer to get better. But my question is more about learning new functions by memorizing techniques (maybe specific to programming).

Comment: That question would fit better to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: For more syntax fun, you can write this `PHRASE_FIRST = len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write code.  Firstly, you will eventually memorise the common built-ins, like `len`, `range`, etc.  There are probably a few that you will never remember at once, these are those you hardly ever use (`eval`, `exec`, `compile`, etc.) but that will depend on the kind of programs you are writing.  That is normal when learning a programming language.

Importantly, learn how to find your way around the documentation.  You might not memorise the exact argument-list for each function, but you should know the kind of features that are available, and how to look it up.

The standard library modules are another matter.  You might only use 10% of them, although some people will use considerably more.  Again, only learn what you need, maybe start at aspects of `sys`.  Even so, there are obscure corners of `sys` that you might never need.

Don't try to remember everything, you don't need to.

Write code.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Do you know of a list of most used/useful functions? learnpythnthehardway lists a few but I believe it's just a few. (ie: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex37.html)

Comment: @faraggi I would start with the [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) and [standard types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html). After that it depends what you are working on, but [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) and [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) seem to come up a lot around here.

Comment: @faraggi: what is useful to me is not necessarily going to be useful to you.  It depends on what your programs need, write code until you need a function.   Here is a complete list: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Just practice I guess.
Also, when doing something that seems "common", check the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/. Like if you want to split strings etc...

It's a pitty there is nothing like [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) (for Haskell) in Python (AFAIK)

Comment: oh wow, Hoogle looks great!
As I answered above, I understand practice makes perfect but how about mnemonic techniques just for learning new functions. I am 31 now and I'm not as quick as I was 15 years ago.

Comment: I understand... I guess, some functions are names similarilly in various languages, so you cna always export your knowledge from one to another. Otherwise, in my case, I don't really have a menonic way to remember (actually, if its been more than 4 months without typing python I always write thing.length() instead of len(thing)...) to me it's just practice and looking on google and the docs whenever something looks like a common thing people would like to do

Comment: @faraggi method of loci?